# AppsScript with Google Sheets: Conditionally load images based on user interaction/when a range is selected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We've got a google sheet with user editable text that will eventually be used within images. We have a web application that generates the images and serves them, so they can be embedded within the IMAGE function provided within Sheets.

This works fine and ends up being something like:
`=IMAGE(CONCAT("PREVIEW_TOOL_URL", "?t=", ENCODEURL(previewText(D2))), 3)` where 'previewText' is simply formatting the string to pass to the web tool.

However, to avoid overloading the server and generating a ton of requests every single time someone loads the sheet, I'd like to make it so images only load in some condition (i.e. a user presses a button or they highlight the text), is there some way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a checkbox to `E2`:

```
=IF(E2,IMAGE(CONCAT("PREVIEW_TOOL_URL", "?t=", ENCODEURL(previewText(D2))), 3),"Check to preview")
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You can also use Apps Script for this!

You will have to start by:

1. Go to *Tools* > *Create a new script*;
2. Use the following script:

```
function loadImages() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID").getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME");
  sheet.getRange("CELL_YOU_WANT_TO_PLACE_THE_FORMULA").setFormula("YOUR_FORMULA");
}
```

Do not forget to adjust this script such that it meets your needs accordingly.

3. Insert a new drawing into the sheet;
4. Attach a script to it by going to the three dots symbol on the drawing; when asked about the name, input `loadImages` which is the function which we had created previously.

[image: sheet button]

5. Press the button on the sheet and that's it!

#### Reference

- [setFormula(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#setFormula(String)).